# How to append something just one time using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I want to add `Jack` in the end of a string only one time. How?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').append('Jack');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>My name is: </div>
<button>click</button>
```

In other word, when I click on that button, if Jack is appended, then nothing happens, but if Jack is not exist, then it appends.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').html('Jack');
});
```

This will replace whatever is inside the div

Comment: In this case the output will be like this: `<div>Jack</div>`. But I want this: `<div>My name is: Jack</div>`

Comment: change 'Jack" to 'My name is: Jack'

Comment: or  following JCD's line of reasoning,  $('button').one('click', function() {
  $('div').append('Jack');
});    which will run just once then remove the event handler automatically.

Comment: @Bindrid I wasn't aware of `one()` until now, that should work too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `on()` and `off()` methods to easily control when event listeners are active.

To add an onclick listener:

```
$("button").on("click", function(){});
```

To remove the listener:

```
$("button").off("click");
```

In your case, you can put the `off()` function call *inside* of the `on()` function's callback. The result is an anonymous function that will run once, on a single click, and then remove itself.

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $("div").append("Jack");
    $(this).off("click");
}
```

Or even better, use `one()`, which will fire only once per element.

```
$("button").one("click", function(){
    $("div").append("Jack");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var text = $('div').text();
  if(!/Jack/.test(text)){
     $('div').append('Jack');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>My name is: </div>
<button>click</button>
```